# Powershell command substitution over SSH

Tags: powershell, ssh

I am trying to connect from a unix server to a windows server via SSH, run a powershell command, and then process the output on the unix server.

The SSH connection and remote execution works without error, and powershell is the login shell presented by the SSH server running on the windows host.

Whenever I try to run a powershell command with command substitution, however, the command substitution is not parsed by powershell but rather is treated as a string literal.

For example, as part of a larger command I want to get the hostname of the windows server. Given a windows host at HOSTNAME, when SSH'd into an interactive powershell session, I can run

```
$ echo "$(hostname)"
HOSTNAME
```

But when running from the unix server

```
$ ssh HOSTNAME "echo \"\$(hostname)\""
"$(hostname)"
```

From my reading, I am inclined to believe that this is due to either a quoting error, which seems unlikely as powershell isn't complaining about syntax, or to powershell operating in a different state than it does when run interactively. The latter seems unlikely as well, but I'm coming from unix/bash to windows/powershell so the general control flow may very well be different than I am accustomed to.

Thus, my question is **how do I get powershell to perform command substitution on remotely executed commands**?

Comment: Does `ssh HOSTNAME 'echo "$(hostname)"'` work? Does `ssh HOSTNAME 'echo (hostname)'`?

Comment: If you are using a string with double quote surrounds you will need to escape the $. In Powershell you escape using the backtick \`.

so `ssh HOSTHAME "echo \`"\`$(hostname)\`""` would be more what you are after.

Comment: @EtanReisner No, neither form works. I still get a literal `$(hostname)` or `(hostname)` back.

Comment: @dwarfsoft Escaping doesn't help, I still get just get a literal `$(hostname)` back. Also, the escape character is \ as the `ssh` command is being run in bash from a unix machine.

Comment: Does normal powershell variable expansion work this way? Can you use `ssh HOSTNAME 'echo $PSVersionTable'` or `ssh HOSTNAME 'echo $PSVersionTable.gettype()'` correctly? Because this sounds like you might not actually be in powershell when the command runs.

Comment: @EtanReisner No, the `echo $PSVersionTable` *doesn't* work. I'm going to see if I'm not accidentally still in `cmd.exe` instead of powershell.